# How to convert to constant expression

Tags: c++, csv

I am writing a .csv importer which takes in a filename and outputs a 2d array.

```
 template<size_t ROW,size_t COL>
 Matrix<double, ROW, COL > importcsv(string filename){
    ifstream myfile (filename);  //Constructs a stream, and then asssociates the stream with the      file "filename"
    vector<double> contentsasvector; // Vector which will store the contents of the stream.
    int i=1; int j=1;
    while(!myfile.eof()){
        if(myfile.get()==','){++j;}
        else if(myfile.get()=='\n'){++i;}
        else{contentsasvector.push_back(myfile.get());}
    }

myfile.close(); // Closes the filestream "my file"
constexpr int rows=i;
constexpr int cols=j/i;
Matrix<double, rows, cols> contents; // Array which will become a 2d version of the vector.
    for (int k = 0; k < rows; ++k){
        for (int l = 0; l < cols; ++l){
            contents[k][l]=contentsasvector[k*(j/i)+l];
        }
    }
    return contents;
}
```

I am baffled that I get the following error message, even though I declared rows and cols to be constexpr. Is there anyway around this?

```
error: non-type template argument is not a constant expression
    Matrix<double, rows, cols> contents; // Array which will become a 2d version of the vector.
                   ^~~~
```

Comment: I don't think `i` or `j` qualify to be used in a `constexpr`, unless the compiler can read the file at compile time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assigning a non-constant value to rows, which means its value is not known at compile time, so you can't use it as a template argument. The compiler should have told you about that though. I'm not sure whether a template is the best thing to use if you are going to choose the row and column number at runtime.